# How to include python with script package?

Tags: python

I'm working on rewriting a software package my employer uses for system health checks from Windows Batch to Python. Is there an easy way to include a Python 2.7 installation with this package, that can be moved around? Or will I have to install Python on the machines I'm running the scripts on each time?

I've looked into Portable Python, but it seems like more of a portable dev environment then a portable installation I can run scripts off of.

Comment: Possible solutions include py2exe, pyinstaller, cx-freeze, etc.

Comment: Well, anywhere you have any Python and any text editor, you have a "dev environment". If your problem with Portable Python is that it has "too many batteries included" you can choose not to install all of them: just uncheck them in the installation process.